# Tailwind For Reactnative Not Working I Am Stuck At The Splashscreen

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I have a reactnative project, I added:

**npm install tailwind-rn**

Imported it into the App.js file

```
**import tw from 'tailwind-rn';
export default function App() { 
   return ( 
          <View style={tw('bg-blue-200 px-3 py-1 rounded-full')}>
             <Text>Hey there!</Text>
           </View>
     ); 
 }**
```

When I launch it in Expo am stuck at the Splashscreen, it doesnt go further. But when I remove the tailwind import and publish it passes the Splashscreen and loads normally.

What can be the cause? Why cant tailwimd-rn work with the app? Once I implement it an run on expo it just get stuck at the Splashscreen.

Comment: It appears you have a syntax error. Do `tw.style('bg-blue-200 px-3 py-1 rounded-full'` However, I've never use tailwind so It's best you read this article (https://blog.logrocket.com/why-you-should-use-tailwind-css-with-react-native/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `''` in the style tag, use `` and remove the `()` bracket in the style tag.